# How to use env variables set from build phase in run. (Docker)

Tags: docker

I want to preface this in saying that I am very new to docker and have just got my feet wet with using it. In my Docker file that I run to build the container I install a program that sets some env variables. Here is my Docker file for context.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN wget http://static.matrix-vision.com/mvIMPACT_Acquire/2.40.0/install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh
RUN wget http://static.matrix-vision.com/mvIMPACT_Acquire/2.40.0/mvGenTL_Acquire-x86_64_ABI2-2.40.0.tgz
RUN chmod +x ./install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh
RUN ./install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh -u
RUN apt-get install -y python3-opencv
RUN pip3 install USSCameraTools 
WORKDIR /app
CMD python3 main.py
```

After executing the build docker command the program "mvGenTL_Acquire.sh" sets env inside the container. I need these variables to be set when executing the run docker command. But when checking the env variables after running the image it is not set. I know I can pass them in directly but would like to use the ones that are set from the install in the build.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you might be looking for an `entrypoint`. Is it possible to send those environment variables to a file and then source it when you run the image?

Comment: `RUN ./install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh -u` will set you some environment variables (temporarily), but as soon as it is finished and exited, the variables are lost. Therefore I would wrap the call of `./install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh -u` in an own developed shell/python/... script, that opens a shell/bash, gets all the environment variables to a cache, runs `./install_mvGenTL_Acquire.sh -u`, gets all the environment variables and compares them with previous version and creates e. g. a file that is ran at startup of the docker image, setting the environment variables... is that understandable?

Comment: Going to try these. thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running a bash script when your container is creating:

make an `script.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
your commands here
```

If you are using an alpine image, you must use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of your bash file.

Now in your Dockerfile copy your bash file in the container and use the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction for running this file when the container is creating:

```
.
.
.

COPY script.sh /
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
.
.
.
ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]
```

Notice that in the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction use your bash file address in your image.

Now when you create a container, the `script.sh` file will be executed.

Comment: So for some reason even when I did this the install was not setting the env variables. The workaround I found though is to just use entrypoint to call a bash file that sets the required env variables based off a text file at runtime.